# No beautifulsoup.py file in bs4 folder?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-import, importerror

I want to see the contents inside the beautifulsoup.py just like in [parse.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFDOw.png)

I installed [bs4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLToK.png), but no `beautifulsoup.py` [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANRXV.png)? I'm expecting to see a "beautifulsoup.py" in "bs4" folder, since importing it is: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Importing `parse` is: `from urllib import parse` which I see a parse.py [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVQxq.png). how about beautiful soup?

Comment: your question is not clear. What you are asking? can  you explain bit more what are you trying to say? Also please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you care how hhe code is organized internally? As long as it does what you want, who cares if it's an alias in `__init__.py` or a file with a particular name?

Comment: @tripleee I'm just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bs4.BeautifulSoup` is not a submodule, it's a class. You can find its definition in [`bs4/__init__.py`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/__init__.py#L56).

---

You can see that it's a class like this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> type(BeautifulSoup)
type
```

… and you can see what file it came from using functions from the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code) module, like:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfile(BeautifulSoup)
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py'
```

---

The syntax `from X import Y` can do two different things:

- If `Y` is a class, function, or other name in `X`, it imports that value from module `X` into your globals as `Y`.
- If `Y` is a submodule under package `X`, it imports that submodule into your globals as module `Y`.

For full details, see [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) in the docs:

> The `from` form uses a slightly more complex process:
>
> 1. find the module specified in the from clause, loading and initializing it if necessary;
> 2. for each of the identifiers specified in the import clauses:
>
>    1. check if the imported module has an attribute by that name
>    2. if not, attempt to import a submodule with that name and then check the imported module again for that attribute
>    3. if the attribute is not found, ImportError is raised.
>    4. otherwise, a reference to that value is stored in the local namespace, using the name in the as clause if it is present, otherwise using the attribute name